# How do I change index of array values with indexes that are null

Tags: c, arrays, validation, arrangeoverride

I was able to do this with an array of 2 indexes, but when I have an array of 3 it only changes the index of one value, and when I have 9 indexes my validation goes alert.

I am trying something like this when inputting 11 in an array of 3 to receive 011, but I get 101.

I have been looking at my second function where I am looping through the indexes to switch values.

```
int validateInt(int digitAmount);
char* validateCharAmount(int charAmount);

int main(void) {
    do{

        printf("Please enter Student's ID': ");
        studentID=validateInt(3);
    }while(studentID!=0);

    return 0;
}

int validateInt(int digitAmount)
{
    int value;
    char *entrySegments;    
    int index=0;
    char temp;
    entrySegments=validateCharAmount(digitAmount);
    while(index<digitAmount){
        while((entrySegments[index]-48)<0 || (entrySegments[index]-48)>9){
            printf("Invalid Value! Please input an integer: ");
            entrySegments=validateCharAmount(digitAmount);
            index=0;
        }
        value=10*value+(entrySegments[index]-48);
        index++;
    }
    printf("%d",value);
    return value;   
}

char* validateCharAmount(int charAmount){

    char entrySegments[charAmount];
    int index=0;
    entrySegments[0]= NULL;
    entrySegments[charAmount]= NULL;
    scanf("%s",entrySegments);
    while(entrySegments[charAmount]!=NULL){
        printf("You entered too many characters! Please input %d: ", charAmount);
        scanf("%s",entrySegments);      
    }
    while(index<charAmount){
        while((entrySegments[index])==NULL){        
            entrySegments[index]=entrySegments[index-1];
            entrySegments[index-1]=48;
        }
        index++;
    }   
    return entrySegments;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable in `validateCharAmount`. Once the function has returned, all local variables cease to exist. The pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: if i have an array of 2 it returns value just fine...

Comment: No it's not fine, it just *seems* like it. Undefined behavior (which is what you have) includes the possibility of seemingly working okay.

Answer (score 1):

`entrySegments` is a local scoped variable inside `validateCharAmount` function.

You cannot return it to the caller because its life ends when the function ends.

You can use [malloc & co](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function to do so.

Moreover `entrySegments[charAmount]` addresses the array out of bounds. Last accessible item is `entrySegments[charAmount-1]`.

Comment: if i have an array of 2 it returns value just fine...

Comment: It is undefined behavior, that means: you are lucky if it works with 2 elements.

Comment: is that the issue that does not make value switching in the array or just an overall analysis

Comment: This is the issue, but you many problems in your code. You are considering an array of chars as array of pointers to strings. You should read a good c book before to code what you want.

Comment: understood, yet i really dont understand how to use malloc, even after reading

Comment: can u help me with an example applying to my issue

Comment: Well, you code is not comprehensible. I can't get what it is supposed to do., and SO is not a code for me service.

Comment: i just missed to add int studentID;